# What's wrong with this HTML page that I created?

Tags: html

I'm taking a programming class on Lynda.com and I just finished creating this HTML web page, but it's not opening on a web browser. Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong? Thanks! :)

Here's what I did:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU9nX.png)

Comment: You should post relevant code to get help by developers. Please take a look here to learn how ask on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and it not only looks correct, it displays for me on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and MS Edge.

I'm thinking that it may be the manner in which you are trying to access the file to display.

Follow these two solutions and see if one of them works for you:

Solution 1) Find where on your hard drive you are saving your "body.html" file. When you find the file, click on it and it should automatically open the file in whatever your default browser is for you.

Solution 2) If you are trying to manually type in the directory address for your "body.html" file inside the web address box of your browser, make sure you are writing the address correctly. Remember, the address is coming from your hard drive and not the internet itself. A format would look something like this:

C:/Website-Projects/body.html

or try:

C://Website-Projects/body.html  (***the only difference is the 2 back slashes instead of one).

in the example above, "C" stands for the designation of my hard drive, "Website-Projects" is the name of the folder on my "C drive" that my target file is in, and "body.html" is the target file I'm trying to open within the "Website-Projects" folder.

Give those two solutions a spin and see if that helps.